# Adding an EditText to a LinearLayout with ListView programmatically (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-search

I'm making a simple android app and I reached a problem I can't solve myself. I searched for a solution quite thoroughly but nothing that I have found seems to work.

In my Main Activity I have a `ListView` which stores data provided by the user.

I want to add a search function to this `ListView`. When I do it statically (add `EditText` in xml and connect with method `addTextChangeListener`) everything works fine. However it's not what I want to achieve.

I want the `EditText` to appear on screen (above the `ListView`) **only** if user clicks on the particular button (which in my app is an action bar item) and then connect it with search function in `ListView`. I tried this:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout;
EditText inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){

    (...)

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputSearch = new EditText(this);

    inputSearch.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    inputSearch.setText("Search...");

    (...)

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    (...)

    case R.id.action_search:

    mainLayout.addView(inputSearch);

    (...)
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't re-create something that's already been made for you. Use the [search widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) which is accessible through the ActionBar, or a [search dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog). Also try to make your questions a little bit more specific

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to use search widget :)